# xampp php not working

Tags: php, xampp

so I have my PHP file (it all works fine the php side of it I know this for a fact) located in xampp's htdocs 'contact.php'

so In my webpage I have it linked up to there "http://localhost/contact.php" however when I press the button and it runs the php i get "Not Found

HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found."

am I linking it wrong? have I put it in the wrong folder (should I put it in the php www folder / how do I link that up?)

I have placed it in the www folder and am having problems still - I am unsure of how to correctly link it to the php www folder.

it is for a contact form - so my action is `<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/contact.php">`

my contact.html is as follows.

```
<div id="contact_form">
            <h4>Send us a message now!</h4>
<form method="POST" action="contact.php">
Fields marked (*) are required

<p>Email From:* <br>
<input type="text" name="EmailFrom">
 <p>Name:* <br>
<input type="text" name="Name">
<p>Email:* <br>
<input type="text" name="Email">
<p>Phone:* <br>
<input type="text" name="Phone">
<p>Message:<br>
<textarea name="Message"></textarea>
 <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I would do if my question was answered

Comment: have tried my solution ?? if problem exist, then you should let us know rather than sitting idle. :/

Comment: yes I tried your solution.  It loads up the php file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Possible problems**

1. Either, your `contact.php` would be in different directory.
2. You are trying to access with **WRONG** URL, i mean path.
3. You would have changed your port number to other. Check your **Port Number**, when you are accessing your main page (i.e. `index.php` or whatever).

**Suggestion**

If your `index.php` and `contact.php` are in same directory i.e. `myproject`. Then, it's better to specify only `contact.php` rather than whole URL.

**Don't**

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/contact.php">
```

**Do**

```
<form method="POST" action="contact.php">
```

**Note : Always use relative URL instead of actual URL.**

**UPDATE**

When you clicked on **SUBMIT** button, then check your current URL path, whether it is changed to `contact.php` or not ?? I mean, it must `localhost/contact.html` to `localhost/contact.php` And I believe, It must. Since, `form` is a part of `html`, which means it doesn't matter whether your server is running or not. But, yes, if your `contact.php` would be in different directory. Then your problem still persist.

Comment: I have changed the port from 80 as 80 was in use and messing up lots of other programs - surely that wouldn't affect it?

Comment: I had them both in the same folder and it just loaded up the php onto my current page (literally showed the file) however when I moved it I was getting 404'd

Comment: check my updated post and update your code accordingly, and let me know, whether problem still there or not ??

Comment: again - I changed it to your suggestion - both in the same folder and it loaded up my php on my page.

Comment: change your code to `<form method="POST" action="contact.php">` as i have mentioned in my post.

Comment: yeah thats what I did , still that problem.

Comment: Are you sure ?? from which page, are you trying to access `contact.php` ?? Please specify that page name. and both are in same directory ?? MAKE SURE.

Comment: my page is 'contact.html' from within there I have a contact form - which is <form method="POST" action="contact.php" > and a submit button - when you press the submit button - it loads the php on the page (everything in the php file is displayed on the screen) both files are in php www folder and apache is running fine in the xampp control panel .

Comment: i will appreciate, if you could share your `contact.html` code. So, that, it makes little easy to us, what is wrong. Update your question by posting the `contact.html` code.

Comment: Dude, it working properly here. I must say, that file (contact.php) would not be in same directory. And, one more thing, form is not a part of `php` it's a part of `html`. So, it doesn't matter whether your server is running or not. After clicking on submit button check your URL, whether it is changed to `contact.php` or not ??

Comment: Yes , when clicking the submit button on the html page - it changes to contact.php

Comment: So, it clear, nothing wrong with my code, the thing, which you would be doing wrong is, either you have put the `contact.php` in wrong directory. It should be in under `htdoc` folder in your project directory or your `contact.php` would be in different directory, may be outside or inside another directory.

Comment: I have tried placing the contact.php in the htdoc folder - however it is still loading up the contact.php file

Answer (score 1):

if it is **`XAMPP`** put in `htdocs` folder  .. your url should be something like this `http://localhost/projectname/index.php/controllername`

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting the question clearly I should say but most likely you have placed the file in the wrong directory. Ensure that the file is located in the htdocs folder under the xampp installation and then try again.

If you are using wamp then you need to place the file in the www folder under the wamp installation.

Answer (score 0):

In xampp put both your html file and the php file in the htdocs directory.

when both files are in the htdocs directory you only need to include the name of the php file

Comment: I have tried that - I put it in the htdocs and am getting the php loading up on the screen